# Configuring open telemetry for tracing service to service calls ONLY

Tags: java, microservices, trace, open-telemetry, distributed-tracing

I am experimenting with different instrumentation libraries but primarily spring-cloud-sleuth and open-telemetry ( OT) are the ones I liked the most. Spring-cloud-sleuth is simple but it will not work for a non-spring ( Jax-RS)project , so I diverted my attention to open telemetry.

I am able to export the metrics using OT, but there is just too much data which I do not need. Spring sleuth gave the perfect solution wherein it just traces the call across microservices and links all the spans with one traceId.

My question is - How to configure OT to get an output similar to spring-sleuth? I tried various configuration and few worked but still the information is huge.

My configuration

```
-Dotel.traces.exporter=zipkin -Dotel.instrumentation.[jdbc].enabled=false -Dotel.instrumentation.[methods].enabled=false -Dotel.instrumentation.[jdbc-datasource].enabled=false
```

However, this still gives me method calls and other data. Also, one big pain is am not able to SHUT DOWN metrics data.

gets error like below

```
ERROR io.opentelemetry.exporter.internal.grpc.OkHttpGrpcExporter - Failed to export metrics. The request could not be executed. Full error message: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:4317
```

Anyhelp will be appreciated - [image]

Comment: I was able to get rid of the metrics error by disabling it using this parameter

-Dotel.metrics.exporter=none

As per official documentation 
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/blob/main/sdk-extensions/autoconfigure/README.md#otlp-exporter-both-span-and-metric-exporters

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to configure the open telemetry agent(otel).

1. Environment variable
2. Java system property

you can either set

```
export OTEL_METRICS_EXPORTER=none
```

or

```
java -Dotel.metrics.exporter=none app.jar
```

**Reference**

https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/blob/main/sdk-extensions/autoconfigure/README.md